# How to activate an item from a menu, when the target is in top scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm improving a small website, where there is a menu fixed in any position of the window, you should activate the item when the ID that this linked is in the window.

To start enternder how it works, I made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kanzer/ydwzwa49/1/ this works well, it is what I want.

This helped me a lot the following code:

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#prime-menu-slide"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });


// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href=#"+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

But in real life, on the site that I want to put it does not work and I cannot understand, why?.
leave the fiddle that does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/kanzer/ev6xn7rc/2/

Thank you for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code doesn't like this kind of links:

```
<a href="#" class="fp_comment_click">Commentaires</a>
```

It's because of this piece of code:

```
scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
```

The code is ok but if `href="#"`, `var item = $("#")` --> error, js dies.

Replace it for something like this (you'll have to figure out the correct anchor):

```
<a href="#historique-et-anecdotes" class="fp_comment_click">Commentaires</a>
```

...and it should [work](http://jsfiddle.net/ev6xn7rc/6/). Or modify the mentioned code bearing in mind the detail I mentioned.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this worked perfect for me in jiddle, even in my page it still does not work. how can I detect in which part is broken?
the console of firefox does not show me anything [my web](http://fr.orkospedia.com/la-noix-de-coco-grande-voyageuse)

Comment: @laur look at the source code of the webpage (you can do it using chrome for instance). Search for <a href="#" . You'll see that you have 6. All of them with the text "Go to ...". However, in your page you don't show those links. Try to get rid of them (if you don't use them) and hopefully it'll work. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, in the end it worked perfectly and my site was not working because I had 2 named elements:#prime-menu-slide I am especified topMenu = $(#otherid #prime-menu-slide)

Comment: @laur you're welcome, glad you managed to solve your problem :)